# Doubt in Apex:chart

Tags: charts, visualforce-charting

how to display the xfield and yfield value only once if the values are repeating in apex:chart.

Thanks in advance,
Abinaya S

Answer (score 1):

I would remove duplicates in the Apex code. You can do that by making use of the technique described in [Using Custom Types in Map Keys and Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm):

```
public class Data {

    public String xfield { get; set; }
    public Integer yfield { get; set; }

    public Boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Data) {
            Data that = (Data) o;
            return this.xfield == that.xfield && this.yfield == that.yfield;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Integer hashCode() {
        return System.hashCode(xfield) + System.hashCode(yfield);
    }
}
```

(The [System.hashCode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_system_system_hashcode) method helps keep things simple by providing access to underlying hashCode logic.)

Then use a set:

```
Set<Data> uniqueSet = new Set<Data>(nonUniqueList);
```

to remove duplicates.